# Визуализировать дисперсии и смещения восстановленной плотности распределения

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, matplotlib, scikit-learn

Имеется задание:

> Визуализировать дисперсии и смещения восстановленной плотности распределения для
>   каждой точки при различных значениях ширины гауссова окна:
>
> - а) рассчитанной по правилу
>     Сильвермана;
> - б) слишком большой ширине окна;
> - в) слишком малой ширине окна.
>
> Использовать поверхности (surface plots) и контурные диаграммы (contour plots).
>
> Для расчета дисперсии в фиксированной точке (x1, x2) восстанавливать плотность
>   распределения по выборке 50 % случайно отобранных данных

Я внёс данные в `pandas.DataFrame` и посчитал KDE (Kernel Density Estimation) по правилу Сильвермана, со слишком большой и слишком малой шириной окна.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x1': random.choices(data['x1'], k=int(len(data['x1']) / 2)),
    'x2': random.choices(data['x2'], k=int(len(data['x2']) / 2))
})

axSilverman = df.plot.kde(bw_method='silverman')
axBig = df.plot.kde(bw_method=3.0)
axSmall = df.plot.kde(bw_method=0.05)
```

Но теперь не понимаю на основании каких данных мне строить контурную диаграмму. Очевидно, что если имеется две выборки x1 и x2, а каждая выборка данных `500 / 2 = 250`, то должно быть две контурные диаграммы, в каждой из которых должно быть 250 точек. А данных для этого никаких нет. `axSilverman.get_positions()` выдаёт что-то вроде

```
Bbox(x0=0.125, y0=0.10999999999999999, x1=0.9, y1=0.88)
```

Помогите разобраться и построить контурные диаграммы.